# What makes this android library a real websocket client library?

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, websocket

https://github.com/koush/android-websockets/blob/master/src/com/codebutler/android_websockets/WebSocketClient.java

What makes it a real websocket client instead of just a straight socket client? I see that it constructs the HTTP request and I'm wondering what is actually the formal "definition" of a websocket vs a normal Java socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebSocket protocol is defined by [IETF 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

The [koush/android-websockets](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets) project implements the IETF 6455 version of the WebSocket protocol.

A WebSocket connection starts with an HTTP compatible handshake that allows it to more easily integrate with existing web infrastructure. It also gives it secure cross-origin capability.

Once the connection is established, the WebSocket connection is full-duplex bi-directional connection (unlike an HTTP long-poll for example). However, the connection is not a raw socket even at this point. WebSocket is message based (rather than streaming like the underlying TCP layer) so it required framing of the data to indicate message boundaries. Each WebSocket frame has at least 2 bytes of header which indicates the length of the frame, whether it is the final frame of a message or a continuation, whether the data is UTF-8 or raw binary, etc.

In addition, client (browser) to server WebSocket frames are masked using a simple running XOR in order to avoid a theoretical vulnerability in web intermediaries (proxies, caches, etc).

Comment: So actually, "WebSocket" doesn't define a particular technology, it's just a protocol definition? And Java's Socket class (which is what Koush's WebSocket is built on) is using the full-duplex bi-directional persistent connection?

Comment: @Tim, not quite. WebSockets is a protocol and an API. The protocol is defined by the IETF (RFC 6455) and the API by the W3C as part of HTML5. koush/android-websockets is a client implementation of the protocol but not the API (although it is similar in spirit). The WebSocket protocol is currently defined to use TCP sockets (yes, just like TCP, it's a protocol in a protocol). And yes, his implementation uses the standard Java socket class.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket deal with HTTP over port 80. And such data can, be both textual and binary as well, but also, known headers - expected markers are easily visible such as HTTP request 302 for example. Whereas, a "normal" Java Socket can be:

- Named pipes
- TCP/IP
- UDP
- Bluetooth

Its rather a more generic socket mechanics where the data speed in terms of binary has maximum throughput.

That would be the "*definition*", but it is not set in stone, for example, you can send binary over a "WebSocket" by encoding it in Base64 prior to sending it over the HTTP.

In Koush's case, he simply ***created a wrapper*** (keyword is *wrapper*) around the standard `Socket` to handle HTTP requests. It is open to interpretation hence it is not set in stone. One can easily create a wrapper around Bluetooth and call it a "*BTSocket*" for example, or even "*IPCSocket*" for Interprocess communication over `Socket`.

Comment: So actually, Koush's "Websocket" wrapper is not referring to the specific technology of a TCP connection that is kept alive for bidirectional transmissions to reduce the number of new connections, but it's just a name he came up with for a HTTP socket?

Comment: Yes, if you observe in his code, there's parsing strategies used to decode the HTTP requests in there, such as `parseStatusLine`, `parseHeader` and `readLine` :)

Comment: This is disappointing. Any idea why he would name it "WebSocket"? Seems like that would be particularly easily confused with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket. As a side note, know any true WebSocket clients for the android SDK?

Comment: I would not say "*disappointing*" Koush has his free-will and reason to call it **WebSocket**. Really, when you step-back and look at the bigger picture, that is all they are in essence a `socket` wrapped around a class to handle specifics of said socket and associated data stream. And no I do not know of any WebSocket clients, best case to look at open-source elsewhere or roll your own :)

Comment: I've looked at the koush/android_websockets code and it does in fact implement IETF 6455 (i.e. real WebSockets).